# Avoiding from MomoryLeak while performing Segues

Tags: memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, segue

I can use navigation without segues (1) but I would like to use it (2).

Performing a segue and navigating back make my app slower ! Because it doesn't dispose destination view when I navigate back. How do you use this segues in a right way ?

```
/*1) This code ok! But what about segues */ 
        if(_tabbarController==null)
        _tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.Storyboard
                           .InstantiateViewController ("MainTabbarController");
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController (_tabbarController,true);

/*2) If I run this code I get  a new instance of UITabbar   */          
      this.PerformSegue("SegueShowDetail",this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Storyboard and a Navigation Controller, the navigation controller should automatically release your view and associated memory with it when it pops off the stack.

For example, if you've got a method that gets called when you push a button to go to another view, you'd have:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueName" sender:self];
```

When you click the back button at the top left of your secondary view, this will trigger the navigation controller to dispose of the view.

Comment: Sure I expect same behavior but I think for `monotouch` things are different. If I use Segue navigation on my app getting extremely slower for a while. AFAIK for Objective-C some automatic de-allocation implemented lately. When I started with it we had should de-alloc manually.